# What does expression *(int*)a mean?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

I don't understand expression `*(int*)a`?

Comment: Is this C or C++? The answer for each language will differ.

Comment: I learn c++ programming

Comment: All the answers you've received so far are C answers. (Although applicable in C++ as well because of C++'s inheritance from C, but not considered good practice in modern C++.)

Comment: @zenith What's the difference in C++? The fact that [casts can be overloaded](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `void *` pointer is a generic pointer, it can point to anything, but as the compiler doesn't know exactly *what* it's pointing to you have to tell the compiler what exactly it's pointing to. This "telling" is what the cast does: `(int *) a` tells the compiler that `a` is actually pointing to an `int`.

Then the code is simply using the dereference operator (unary `*`)  to get the value of where `a` is pointing and using that in a normal subtraction expression.

Answer (score 4):

```
(int*)a
```

casts `a` to `int*`. Simply dereferencing `a` doesn't work because `*a` would have type `void`, which is not allowed.

Furthermore, this is somewhat unsafe here as `a` is passed as `const` and the caller expects `*a` not to be changed. OK, `a` isn't changed indeed but such an explicit conversion should be a rarity.

The additional dereferencing "gets" the value `a` points to. In the end, `compare` returns `0` if both data are equal.

Answer (score 0):

`(int*)a` converts void pointer to int type pointer. `*(int*)a` takes the value that the pointer points to.

Comment: "takes the value of that pointer", __no__, it _dereferences_ that pointer, i.e. takes the value that the pointer _points to_. The "value of [the] pointer" would be the memory address it stores. Btw you put the asterisk in the wrong place, it's `(int*)a` not `(int)a*`, the latter doesn't compile, and if it does it does the wrong thing.

Comment: Sorry ... I meant that. :) And thanks for correcting me.